# Open connection trouble when trying to insert data into SQL Server database

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have created a `Main` form with password request to login to next form depend on a username. Now here I have made another form with tabs. One tab for inserting data, other one for checking data.

I have create the form like this [Picture](http://prntscr.com/24jg7s)

This is my code:

`

```
namespace Kartice
{
    public partial class Matjaz : Form
    {
    //   string KarticaMString = "Data Source=hostname;Initial Catalog=mydatabase;uid=uid;pwd=pwd;Integrated Security=True;";
      // SqlConnection KarticaM = new SqlConnection();
        public Matjaz()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

    private void karticaMBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    private void usersBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    private void usersBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    private void karticaMBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    private void Matjaz_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'kartice1.KarticaM' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        this.karticaMTableAdapter.Fill(this.kartice1.KarticaM);

    }

    private void tabPage1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void ExitBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Exit();

    }

    private void InsertBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string Sqlquery = null;
       string  KarticaMString = null;

        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(KarticaMString))
        {
            {
                Sqlquery = "INSERT INTO KarticaM (DateInsert, DateTransaction, Value, Purpose, DepositLift) VALUES (" + DateInsertPicker.Value + "," + DateTransactionPicker.Value + "," + ValueTxt.Text + "," + PurposeTxt.Text + "," + DepositLiftCombobox.SelectedText + ")";
                conn.Open();
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(Sqlquery, conn))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@DateInsert", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateInsertPicker.Value;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@DateTransaction", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTransactionPicker.Value;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Value", SqlDbType.Money).Value = ValueTxt.Text;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Purpose", SqlDbType.Text).Value = PurposeTxt.Text;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("DepositLift", SqlDbType.Text).Value = DepositLiftCombobox.SelectedValue;

                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    cmd.Connection = conn;
                }
                conn.Close();
            }
        }

    }
  }
}
```

I got this error :( [Error](http://prntscr.com/24jes7)

Comment: what is in KaricaMString?
but you use commandParameters, but in SqlQuery dont use it...

Comment: What is unclear about the message? The connection string is not set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Though your major or first Problem is `ConnectionString` is `null`, i could also find other errors from your code:

**1.** Your `ConnectionString`  is `null` .

```
 string  KarticaMString = null;//assign your connection string here    
 using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(KarticaMString))
```

**Solution:**

assign the proper `Connection String` before assigning it to the `SqlConnection` object.

**Example:**

```
string  KarticaMString = "Data Source=hostname;Initial   
Catalog=mydatabase;uid=uid;pwd=pwd;Integrated Security=True";
```

**2.** your `Insert Into` Statement can be attacked using `SQL Injection`.
**Solution:** Use `Parametrised Queries`.

**3.**  though you are assigning parameters using `SqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue()` they will not  be reflected to your `sql statement` untill unless you specify those parameters in the sql statement.

**Solution:** first add the parameters in `insert into` statement then add the values to the respective parameters using `SqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue()` statement.

**4.** you are assigning the `SqlConnection` object after calling the `ExecuteNonQuery()` Statement.
**Solution:** Not Required as you have already done it before.

**5.** *suggestion:* what i feel is you dont need to close the `SqlConnection` object explicitly as you have declared it inside the `using{}` block, object Disposal willbe taken care  by using block
**Solution:**  Remove the statement  `conn.Close();`

**Final Solution**

```
private void InsertBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       string Sqlquery = null;
       string  KarticaMString = "@Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Bojan\Desktop\Programiranje\School‌​\Kartice\Kartice\Kartice.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";

        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(KarticaMString))
        {

                Sqlquery = "INSERT INTO KarticaM (DateInsert, DateTransaction, Value, Purpose, DepositLift) VALUES (@DateInsert,@DateTransaction,@Value,@Purpose,@DepositLift)";
                conn.Open();
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(Sqlquery, conn))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@DateInsert", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateInsertPicker.Value;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@DateTransaction", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTransactionPicker.Value;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Value", SqlDbType.Money).Value = ValueTxt.Text;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Purpose", SqlDbType.Text).Value = PurposeTxt.Text;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@DepositLift", SqlDbType.Text).Value = DepositLiftCombobox.SelectedValue;

                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();                    
                }


        }

    }
```

Comment: public partial class Matjaz : Form
    {
       public string KarticaMString = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Bojan\Desktop\Programiranje\School\Kartice\Kartice\Kartice.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";
       SqlConnection KarticaM = new SqlConnection();`

I have first lines like this, dont know how to put them in code

Comment: Sudhakar; I still got error on conn.Open(); can you explain more if you can, please :(

Comment: @Peca: check my edited answer now, sorry it was my typing mistake.

Comment: @p.s.w.g: Sorry Sir, i have edited my Answer properly it was Typo, please let me know if there are any mistakes?

Comment: :) Thanks a lot... let me see how it solves the OP's problem.

Comment: @Sudhakar I have also problem with your code... i got this error on conn.open();

An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file C:\Users\Bojan\Desktop\Programiranje\School‌​\Kartice\Kartice\Kartice.mdf failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share.

Comment: @Sudhakar An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file C:\Users\Bojan\Desktop\Programiranje\School‌​\Kartice\Kartice\Kartice.mdf failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share.

this is saying...

Comment: @Sudhakar I can also send you printscreen how I have database or .cs

Comment: @Peca: did you send me any mail?

Comment: No I didnt send you nothing, My mail is matjaz.pecavar@gmail.com

Comment: Okay please check your inbox i have sent you TestMail.

Comment: Sorry i went to store... I'm sendein you mail :)

Answer (score 2):

Notice this:

```
string KarticaMString = null;

using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(KarticaMString))
{
    ...
}
```

The connection string, `KarticaMString`, is obviously `null`. You'll have to provide a valid connection string to the [`SqlConnection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) constructor. See [`ConnectionString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for more information on how to write a valid connection string, or use a [`SqlConnectionStringBuilder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).